# Is there a way to have two aliases to a user's profile page?

Tags: path-aliases

Is there a way to have two aliases to a user's profile page?

We are currently using the user paths setting at admin/build/path/pathauto - but we would like to have another path set up for the same page if that is possible.

Currently we have one path set to be:
users/[content-profile-directory-preferred_first_name-raw]-[content-profile-directory-lastname-raw]

We would like to setup a second path to the same user's profile page that would be just:
users/[user-raw]

Thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want to manually maintaing the second alias - since pathauto only allows you to generate a single automatic alias - then perhaps the easiest way is to use Rules, instead of pathauto. It's been a few years since I did this, and it was for node aliases, not user page aliases, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

1. Setup a Rule with multiple steps to create the aliases you need - you can use all the same token substitutions in Rules as you can in pathauto
2. Run the rule when a user is created